# How to add a value and row number to json pretty print

Tags: python

I'm new to python. In my python script I have a sql query where the results are read into pandas dataframe (pd.read_sql). The results have 2 columns: BRANCH and PROFILE. PROFILE is json. I do a json.loads to convert PROFILE to dictionary then a json.dumps to pretty print to a file. What I would like to do is write the BRANCH and a line number before each row. How can I do this? Thank you.
For example (`BRANCH LINE_NUMBER JSON(pretty print)`):

```
1234 1 {
1234 2  "name": "Sky Bank",
1234 3  "address": "8745 Main St"
1234 4 }
5678 1 {
5678 2  "name": "Tree Credit Union",
5678 3  "address": "5023 S Ave"
5678 4 }
```

I've googled and haven't found anything.

Comment: The result you want isn't json anymore, so the standard json functions won't be any help.  You'll have to code it yourself.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to pretty format the output from the SQL query (you have branch ID and a python dict for each row from the query):

```py
import json

def pretty_print(data, indent=1):
    out = []
    for branch_id, d in data:
        d = json.dumps(d, indent=indent)
        for n, l in enumerate(d.splitlines(), 1):
            out.append(f'{branch_id:>4} {n:>3} {l}')
    return '\n'.join(out)

data = [
    (1234, {"name": "Sky Bank", "address": "8745 Main St"}),
    (5678, {"name": "Tree Credit Union", "address": "5023 S Ave"}),
]

print(pretty_print(data))
```

Prints:

```
1234   1 {
1234   2  "name": "Sky Bank",
1234   3  "address": "8745 Main St"
1234   4 }
5678   1 {
5678   2  "name": "Tree Credit Union",
5678   3  "address": "5023 S Ave"
5678   4 }
```